# Spring @Autowired gives new instance instead of initialized session scoped bean

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I am developing application using Spring and I need to initialize Ticket object in session and then get it from another controller.

I have two controllers, so there are two xml contexts.

> web.xml

```
    <web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

   <display-name>Spring Web MVC Application</display-name>

   <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>

   <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-context.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>

   <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
   </listener>

   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
         <param-value>/WEB-INF/rest-context.xml</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
         <param-value>/WEB-INF/index-context.xml</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

> rest-context.xml

```
<beans ...>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>    
    <context:annotation-config/>    
    <context:component-scan base-package="menu.MenuController"/>    
</beans>
```

> index-context.xml

```
<beans ...>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/**" location="/"/>

    <context:annotation-config/>    
    <bean class="auth.IndexWebController" />    
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"/>
</beans>
```

In the spring-context I have my Ticket bean:

```
<bean id="tickerProvider" class="TicketProviderImpl" scope="session">
    <aop:scoped-proxy/>
```

together with the other beans.

This are what my controllers look like:

> IndexWebController.java

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("user")
public class IndexWebController {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IndexWebController.class);

    @Autowired
    private TicketProviderImpl ticketProvider;

    @ModelAttribute("user")
    public User populateUser() {
        return new User();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})
    public ModelAndView printIndex(@ModelAttribute("user") User user,
                                   @RequestParam(value = "iv-user", required = false) String login,
                                   @RequestParam(value = "iv-groups", required = false) String groups) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
            modelAndView.setViewName("index.html");

<...>            
        ticketProvider.setLogin(login);
                logger.info("Пользователь установлен в " + login);
    <...>
```

> MenuController.java

```
@Controller
public class MenuController {

    @Autowired
    private TicketProviderImpl ticketProvider;

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping("/getMenuList")
    public MenuListDTO getMenuList(


             @RequestParam(value = "menuId", required = true, defaultValue = "-1") long menuId,
                @RequestParam(value = "parentId", required = true, defaultValue = "0") long parentId) {

<...>
            System.out.println(ticketProvider.getLogin());
<...>

        }
    }
```

The problem is that when I autowire ticketProvider bean in the MenuController I get a new instance of it, not those that has been initialized in the IndexWebController. Actually I get null, but waiting for the login.

Where is the mistake or some misunderstanding of using session scoped beans?

Answer (score -1):

According to [this](https://tuhrig.de/making-a-spring-bean-session-scoped/) you will need another listener to expose your session to the application.
Hence adding `<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>` should do the trick.

Comment: I'm wondering, did you resolve the issue? My answer got downvoted and I am curious as of why? @Andrey Z.